# How to delete iCloud account without knowing the password

Tags: icloud, password, accounts

I want to delete iCloud Account, but I can't remember the password to gain access to my Apple iCloud. Can someone please help me as there must be away that I can delete the account.

Comment: start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

You need access to an iCloud account to delete it, therefore you will need to regain access. If you have forgotten the password, try [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you call apple they can attempt to verify your identity if successfully they can send you a reset link after 24 hours to a email address

Answer (score -3):

there isn't a way without the password, :(