# Delete iCloud account from mac when the iCloud account doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: macos, icloud

I recently deleted my iCloud account and while doing so forgot to remove it from my iMac first.

Now, I get persistent notifications on my mac saying to "fix it", but in order to fix it, I have to remove the account. I cannot remove the account since it requires a password to do that, and when I enter the password it says "Account not found" (or something along those lines).

I called Apple support and their recommendation was to create a new user account and delete the old one. But doing that is an insane hassle since I have a very complex user account set up (I work as a software developer).

Is there a way to simply get this account off of my computer? Or, is there an easier way to fully migrate my entire user account over to a new user account without losing anything? (Including configurations in places like `~/.bashrc` , `~/.bash_profile`, desktop wallpaper, mouse scroll sensitivity, key repeat speed, etc.

If the solution for removing the apple account is fairly technical, I do not mind that. I would prefer not to have to create a new user account on my computer if at all possible.

I would even settle for leaving the broken iCloud account on there but being able to get rid of the intrusive prompts i get every now and again asking me to fix it.

This is the prompt I see constantly:

[image: the prompt]

When I go into settings, I see this:

[image]

And when I try to click "Sign Out", and enter my old password, i see this

[image]

Comment: Your account takes some time to get deleted I hope? also try raising an concern with the key they gave you as the ticket id. Also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180001/how-to-delete-icloud-account-without-knowing-the-password?rq=1

Comment: @ankii I don't really understand your comment. Regarding the first part: My account was already deleted, the iCloud account that is. My local User Account is what Apple recommended i re-create. There is no support ticket for this, I spoke to them over the phone.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjCyY.png